# Creating a workflow which automatically runs a formula to assign customized number

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, calculated-column

I have created a list which uses a calculated column to assign a customized change control number.  However, whenever a new item is created/saved, the formula is not applied.

It is only when I access through list settings and open the calc column and then save, does the desired outcome display.

I am new to workflows and need help getting started.

Comment: What version of SharePoint is it? I had seen this issue in SharePoint 2007

Comment: It's the 2010 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This calculated column behavior (`a new item is created/saved, the formula is not applied`) usually occurs in case you are using the **ID** field in your calculated column formula.

> **Note:** the **ID** field is not calculated in the calculated column to until the formula is updated/changed again in the calculated column field settings,  so it's not supported to use it in the calculated column.

> Check the full list of **[supported and unsupported fields in the SharePoint Calculated Column Formula.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5KOu.png)**

[image: https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/id-field-in-calaulated-column-sharepoint/]

---

**The workaround.**

- [Use SharePoint ID Field in Calculated Column Using SharePoint Designer Workflow.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/id-field-in-calaulated-column-sharepoint/)
- [Create an Auto-Incremental ID field in Calculated Column Using JSOM.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/auto-serial-number-new-form-sharepoint/)
- Build a Calculated Column formula in SharePoint using an Event Receiver.